# Proof that spanning set is greater than linearly independent subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Let *G* be a set that generates *V* containing *n* vectors and *H* be a linearly independent subset of *V* containing *m* vectors. Prove that $m \le n$.
My attempt:
We will use a proof by induction with base case $m=0$.
$m=0$ implies that $H =∅$ and since *m* cannot be less than $0$, $m \le n$.

Our induction hypothesis is that the theorem holds for some $n>0$. We need to show that it holds for $m+1$, ie. $m+1 \le n$.

Suppose the opposite, that 
$m+1 \ge n$ 
$\implies m>n$ which cannot be true but I am not sure how to prove it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

If $G = \{ v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ generates $V$, then $n \geq\dim V $ by the definitions of basis and dimension. If $H = \{w_1, \cdots, w_m \}$ has $m$ linearly independent vectors, again by the definitions of basis and dimension we have $m \leq \dim V$. So $m \leq \dim V \leq n$, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: If I am correct, I think this fact is used in proving the definition of a basis as a least linear independent subset so this would be a cyclical proof.